# Delphi to c++ translation issue

Tags: delphi

i ran into an issue transfering Delphi code to C++.
What does "Max(...) < 1 then" do?

Here the Delphi code:

```
if (Distance(CameraPosition, CellCenterPos)/(Size*2*C*
  Max([smallC*D2Matrix[X,Z], 1.0])))<1 then
begin

function Max(const Values : Array of Single): Single;
var
 I : Integer;
begin
 Result := 0;
  for I := Low(Values) to High(Values) do
   if (Values[I] > Result) then Result := Values[I]
end;
```

Comment: What don't you understand? `if`? `Max`? `<`?

Comment: [smallC*D2Matrix[X,Z], 1.0]. Max takes an array but this don't look like an array to me

Comment: That's an open array constructor. Read about it in the documentation.

Comment: So its like an Array with 2 values?

Comment: Yes. Did you read the documentation?

Comment: I do at the moment. thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Delphi code is not performing `Max(...) < 1`.  `Max()` is inside of parenthesis with other calculations. The code is actually performing `(Distance(...) / (... * Max(...)) < 1`

The Delphi code translates to something like this in C++:

```cpp
float Max(const float Values[], int NumValues)
{
    float Result = 0;
    for(int I = 0; I < NumValues; ++I) {
        if (Values[I] > Result)
            Result = Values[I];
    }
    return Result;
}

float arr[] = {smallC * D2Matrix[X,Z], 1.0};
if ((Distance(CameraPosition, CellCenterPos) / (Size * 2 * C * Max(arr, 2))) < 1)
{
    ...
}
```

Or:

```cpp
template <size_t N>
float Max(const float (&Values)[N])
{
    float Result = 0;
    for(int I = 0; I < N; ++I) {
        if (Values[I] > Result)
            Result = Values[I];
    }
    return Result;
}

const float arr[] = {smallC * D2Matrix[X,Z], 1.0};
if ((Distance(CameraPosition, CellCenterPos) / (Size * 2 * C * Max(arr))) < 1)
{
    ...
}
```

Or:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>

float arr[] = {smallC * D2Matrix[X,Z], 1.0};
if ((Distance(CameraPosition, CellCenterPos) / (Size * 2 * C * (*std::max_element(arr, arr+2)))) < 1)
{
    ...
}
```

Or: (C++11 and later only):

```cpp
#include <algorithm>

if ((Distance(CameraPosition, CellCenterPos) / (Size * 2 * C * std::max({smallC * D2Matrix[X,Z], 1.0}))) < 1)
{
    ...
}
```